# python division result different with negative number

Tags: python, python-2.7

While playing with python command line I notice the following:

```
Python 2.7.3 |EPD_free 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 11 2012, 17:52:16)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
Type "credits", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
>>> 9/7
1
>>> -9/7
-2
>>>
```

Could someone indicate why my answer is different with negative number division? Thanks.

Comment: It's not different, it always rounds down.

Comment: Division always rounds downwards to negative infinity.

Comment: If you treated them as floats then: `9.0/7.0, -9.0/7 ->(1.2857142857142858, -1.2857142857142858)`... And since it rounds down as others have mentioned... there ya go

Comment: Try [`from __future__ import division`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) to switch from floor division to true division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.X, `/` is actually floor division for ints and longs:

> The current division (/) operator has an ambiguous meaning for numerical arguments: it returns the floor of the mathematical result of division if the arguments are ints or longs, but it returns a reasonable approximation of the division result if the arguments are floats or complex.  This makes expressions expecting float or complex results error-prone when integers are not expected but possible as inputs. [source: [PEP 238]](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

If you want to use true division with ints/longs, you can add `from __future__ import division` to your module (or by switching to 3.X). If you do this, you can use floor division by doing `x//y`.

```
>>> 9/7
1
>>> -9/7
-2
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 9/7
1.2857142857142858
>>> -9/7
-1.2857142857142858
```

Answer (score 2):

Because integer division is rounded to nearest lower integer.

Answer (score 1):

It's like the [Floor and ceiling functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) , you will get that because you're using integer numbers

You can try the int() function if you want it to be "equal" in terms of values,
like this

```
>>> int(9/7.0)
1
>>> int(-9/7.0)
-1
```

You can put one or both of the numbers with the ".0" in order to get a floating point